# Do we have enough information to determine who Garona's father is?

Tags: warcraft, warcraft-2016

In the [*Warcraft* (2016)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warcraft_(film)) movie, the character [**Garona Halforcen**](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Garona_(movie)) (Paula Patten) doesn't seem to know who her father is.

However, at some point during the movie, [**Medivh**](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Medivh_(movie)) (Ben Foster) explains to her that

> he found some strong race of beings and mated with one of their females, and left her with child.

I'm wondering if the writers intended for this to be foreshadowing of her father's identity?

There was also the point where **Anduin Lothar** (Travis Fimmel) mentioned something like:

> You don't look so different from us

Meaning that she seems to be Half-Orc / Half-Human.

There's also an [article](http://www.hitfix.com/harpy/fun-fact-warcraft-quietly-changed-the-origin-story-of-one-its-crucial-heroes) written by Donna Dickens which confirms Garona's half-human origin as well as that

> Medivh ... is now the father of (Garona). 
> <sup>*-http://www.hitfix.com/harpy/fun-fact-warcraft-quietly-changed-the-origin-story-of-one-its-crucial-heroes#PcG2cGjbu0oFexxj.99*</sup>

**Is there any official statement about who Garona's father is?**

Answer (score 3):

Although there is no specific official statement from Blizzard,

> Medivh being Garona's father

is being taken as the intended implication **baring further information**, as is being cited in [various wiki pages](http://wow.gamepedia.com/Garona_Halforcen_%28film_universe%29#Warcraft).

This is a major change from the accepted lore of the games.

Comment: It's *kind of* a major change.  Garona being half-human (and potentially Medivh's daughter?) was how the character was originally written.  Until someone - correctly - pointed out this was utter nonsense, as orcs and humans hadn't even been on the same planet until the Dark Portal opened, and Medivh only ever saw the orcs through mind-links.  There simply was never enough time in those events for her to grow up.  If the movie puts him there physically, then the original story is viable again.  In a boomerang-retcon-whirlwind sort of way.

Comment: @Radhil do you have source for being originally Half-Human? Within the game lore that I can find, she's often referred to as Half-Draenai, as [detailed here](http://wowwiki.wikia.com/wiki/Garona_Halforcen#Parentage)

Comment: @sequoiad The game lore that you can find now has been revised multiple times compared to how things were in the days of Orcs and Humans. In the Last Guardian book, she refers to herself as half-human (she points to her hand and asks Khadgar what he sees, and he says "Orc", and she says that an Orc would see human hands, which would make no sense if they knew she was half-Draenei). The half-human thing was also mentioned in the Warcraft I manual iirc. "Draenei" weren't ever really a thing until Burning Crusade (the only references to Draenei before that were to Broken in WCIII and WoW).

Comment: Welp, [here's a link to a copied section of the Warcraft I manual](http://wow.gamepedia.com/Warcraft:_Orcs_%26_Humans_manual#The_Destiny_of_the_Orcish_Hordes), and Garona herself seems to believe it's the case, as she repeats this claim in the novel *The Last Guardian*, chapter eleven.  Medivh in the same book thinks there are nearly-humans on Draenor, as nothing else would make sense.  That novel is from 2002 - by 2005, there's a tweet from Blizzard staff confirming she's half Draenei, not half-human, and the Burning Crusade was out 2 years later.

Comment: *The Official Movie Novelization* is the source. Note however, that it is more of a difference than a change, because the original Garona from World of Warcraft canon is still half-draenei (retconned from being half-human pre-BC).